# examples of functions analytic only in strip (0,1) and with natural boundaries Re(z)=0,1?

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, examples-counterexamples

Looking for examples of functions that are analytic only in the strip $(0,1)$ and with natural boundaries $\Re(z)=0,1.$

I thought of modular forms but they only have one natural boundary I think.

Comment: another way to do it is to pick your favorite function $f$  defined on $\Re z >0$ with natural boundary $\Re z =0$ and take $g(z)=f(z)+f(1-z)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a known example with natural boundary.  Say $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{2^n}$ with natural boundary $|z|=1$.  Then use a conformal mapping $\varphi$ that maps your strip onto $|z| < 1$.  Then $f(\varphi(z))$ is your answer.